# Why does IBM Cloud give server error while applying feature code?

Tags: cloud, websphere

Why does IBM Cloud give server error while applying feature code in "Subscription and feature codes" under account settings ?

Comment: Please contact IBM Cloud support.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.